# Saving and loading a datetime object as npy/ pickle format

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I am trying to calculate the difference between two timestamps in minutes, if the difference is greater than a threshold I will perform a task. So far I have tried to do the difference but it's giving an error as the datetime difference isn't giving me any numeric value.

I also need to save the first datetime object as numpy array/pickle instead of a database column as it's more convenient for my task.

```
import datetime
import time

a = datetime.datetime.now() # save this timestamp for later comparison

# save as numpy array

# load the array

time.sleep(100) # program closes, and re-opens

b = datetime.datetime.now()

# comparison in minutes

diff = b-a

# if diff > 60 minutes, do something

if diff > 60:
  pass
```

Error I'm getting:

```
---> 20 if diff > 60:
     21   pass
     22 

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your updated code.

```
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np

a = datetime.datetime.now() # save this timestamp for later comparison

np_format = np.array([a.year, a.month, a.day, a.hour, a.minute, a.second, a.microsecond]) # all numeric values
np.save('date_old.npy', np_format)

a_load = np.load('date_old.npy')

a_loaded = datetime.datetime(a_load[0], a_load[1], a_load[2], a_load[3], a_load[4], a_load[5], a_load[6])

print(a)

print(a_loaded)

# save as numpy array

# load the array

time.sleep(100) # program closes, and re-opens

b = datetime.datetime.now()

# comparison in minutes

diff = (b-a_loaded).total_seconds()/60.

# if diff > 60 minutes, do something
print(diff)
if diff > 1:
  print('hello')
```

Output:

```
2020-04-12 18:14:29.439318
2020-04-12 18:14:29.439318
1.6676882
hello
```